# Is there a way to recognize text title in textview as ID in Android Studio for Java?

Tags: java, android

I have a playsongactivity page that retrieves data from another Java class page called `SongCollection` that stores song information. I set the ID for these songs as "S1, S2 ... etc" as that is the ID for the imageviews I have placed in my mainactivity so that users get redirected to the playsongactivity page with the correct song playing.

I have set up a similar `playlistsactivity` page and created another Java class page called `AlbumCollection`. That data is retrieved from when users click on an album image and get redirected to `albumsactivity`.

I would like the user to be able to click on the song name that appears after being redirected to `albumsacitivty` and be brought to the `playsongactivity` page with the correct song information being retrieved.

Is there a method to retrieve song data based on the album data retrieved? I am relatively new to this, so I apologize if I've missed out on any relevant information that is required please correct me.